# Trying to go to a certain step after its completed one in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

Alright. I want it so the following would happen, Heres a sample:

```
puts "what would you like to see?"
var = gets.chomp
if var == "z"
  puts "this"

elsif var == "d"
  puts "stack"

elsif var == "y"
  puts "overflow"

else
  puts "I don't understand that."

end
```

Currently it works fine up until I want to have the user redefine the 'var'. Currently all the loops just loop back the puts from the elsif - i want it to ask for the user input again, then print out the elsif to that.
For example:
User types in `y`, the code would say `overflow`, then return to line 1. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Doing `if foo = bar` doesn't give a warning even if warnings are turned on. I'm a bit surprised at that...

Answer (score 3):

`gets` returns `nil` when there is no input, and since `nil` evaluates to false in a conditional, you can use `gets` in a loop like so

```
while var = gets
  var.chomp!
  if var == "z" # use == to test equality, not =
    # do stuff
  elsif var == "x"
    # do stuff
  ....
end # while
```

You might find this works better with a `case` statement:

```
while var = gets
  case var.chomp
  when "z"
    puts "this"
  when "d"
    puts "stack"
  when "y"
    puts "overflow"
  else
    puts "I don't understand that."
  end # case
end # while
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the assignment operator (`=`) where you mean to test equality (`==`), I think.

You could also use `case`, but here's a version with `while` and `if`

```
print "Gimme an answer ('q' to quit) >> "
response = gets.chomp

while response != 'q'
  if response == 'z'
    puts "this"
  elsif response == 'd'
    puts "stack"
  elsif response == 'y'
    puts "overflow"
  else
    puts "I don't understand that."
  end

  print "Gimme another answer ('q' to quit) >> "
  response = gets.chomp
end
```

Comment: Was just a typo. Thats what i'm using in my real code, sorry about that... gonna edit it.